# Convert jQuery Script to YUI: Checkboxes checked get copied into a custom widget

Tags: jquery, yui

I am using RightNow CRM software and part of coding our support portal is that I have to use YUI scripting as opposed to jQuery because of best practices (use only one scripting library). I have included the jQuery script that I want to convert to YUI and my YUI "translation" that I attempted. Any help would go a long way, I was using [this website](http://www.jsrosettastone.com/) to carry out these translations.

[jQuery script](http://jsfiddle.net/c97Tu/)

```
$(function() {
$('input').on('click', function() {
    var values = [];
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
        values.push($(this).parent().text());
    });
    $('[name="result"]').attr({value: values.join(', ')});
});
});
```

[YUI script](http://jsfiddle.net/uMxat/)

```
YUI().use('node', 'io', 'event', 'animation', function (Y) {
Y.all('input[type=checkbox]').delegate('click', function(Y) {
    var values = [];
    Y.all('input:checked').each(function(Y) {
        values.push((this).parent().text());
    });
    Y.one('result').setAttribute({value: values.join(', ')});
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this... Actually I can't test and thus I'm trying to guess what it should do. And also a few improvements to your "translation".

```
YUI().use('node', 'io', 'event', 'animation', function (Y) {
    Y.all('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(event) {
        var values = [];
        Y.all('input:checked').each(function(checkbox) {
            values.push(checkbox.ancestor().getHTML());
        });
        Y.one('[name=result]').set( "value", values.join(', ') );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Awesome! I tested it, it worked but was showing the html; I changed your ".getHTML" tag to "get('text')" and it works perfectly! [You can see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/uMxat/2/)

```
YUI().use('node', function (Y) {
Y.all('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(event) {
    var values = [];
    Y.all('input:checked').each(function(checkbox) {
        values.push(checkbox.ancestor().get('text'));
    });
    Y.one('[name=result]').set( "value", values.join(', ') );
});
});
```